# Are there two Vashista Maharishi?

Tags: vashishta, gotra, saptarshi

Some people claim that there were two Vashista Maharishi one among the saptarishi and the other is brother of Kaundinya Maharishi. When I say my pravara it is "Vashista-Maitravarna-Kaundinya triyarishi". Is this claim true? If yes please explain their life briefly.